# Android BottomNavigationView item text not clickable

Tags: android, kotlin, menuitem, bottomnavigationview, clickable

I'm using a [BottomNavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView) but somehow I can't navigate to another item when I exactly click on the item's text because the click gets intercepted. This is a big problem as the text takes up half of the button. If I do a longpress it actually selects the text...
Here is my code:

**build.gradle**

```
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0"
```

I've also tried 1.3.0-alpha01 but the problem still persists.

**OnNavigationItemSelectedListener in my activity.**

```
private fun getBottomNavigationItemSelectedListener() = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
    when (item.itemId) {
        bottomNavigation.selectedItemId -> {
            false
        }
        R.id.bottom_navigation_overview -> {
            navigateTo<OverviewActivity>()
            true
        }
        R.id.bottom_navigation_settings -> {
            navigateTo<SettingsActivity>()
            true
        }
        R.id.bottom_navigation_help -> {
            navigateTo<HelpActivity>()
            true
        }
        else -> false
    }
}
```

**layout of the activity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomNavigation" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fragmentContainer"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**menu layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_overview"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_bottom_nav_overview"
        android:title="@string/BottomNavigation_overview" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_settings"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_bottom_nav_settings"
        android:title="@string/BottomNavigation_settings" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_help"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_bottom_nav_help"
        android:title="@string/BottomNavigation_help" />
</menu>
```

When I turn on the layout boundaries it is clear that the item text is the problem:

**First item selected (no problem)**
[image: first item]

**Tried to selected second item but the text intercepts the click**
[image: second item with no luck]

What should I do so the item text doesn't intercept the click? I don't see what I'm doing different from [the examples](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-navigation/) that android provides, and I doubt that this is the default behaviour.

Comment: Why do you want to make text clickable ?

Comment: @MD I don't want the text to intercept the click that is supposed to be handled by the BottomNavigationView-item

Comment: Did you called `getBottomNavigationItemSelectedListener()` anywhere in your code? Can you post that code block also?

Comment: Can you try that in some other device or emulator?

Comment: Ive found the cause and a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62714033/2212770). But thanks for trying to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just when I've finished writing this question I've found the cause of the problem. We've made every single TextView in our app selectable with a style.

**themes.xml**

```
<style name="BaseTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/TextViewStyle</item>
</style>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="TextViewStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextView">
    <!-- other styling -->
    <item name="android:textIsSelectable">true</item>
</style>
```

As a result the `TextView` of the `BottomNavigationView`-`Item` will intercept all clicks.

We still want most of our `TextViews` to be selectable, just not the `TextView` within the `BottomNavigationView`. So I created a new theme that inherits from the base-theme and a new style that inherits the other TextView-style:

**themes.xml**

```
<style name="BottomNavigationTheme" parent="BaseTheme">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/TextViewStyle.NoTextSelection</item>
</style>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="TextViewStyle.NoTextSelection" parent="@style/TextViewStyle">
    <item name="android:textIsSelectable">false</item>
</style>
```

Next I added the theme to the BottomNavigationView located in my layout

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/BottomNavigationTheme"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fragmentContainer"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

And this solved my problem.

Comment: Sometime what we don't want to do intercepts everything we have done. :(